# (PHP/MySQL) How can I set a new address as the "new" default and unset the previous one?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I was able to set an address as the default through SQL UPDATE statement but I couldn't make it appear on the page where I show the default addresses of the user because the previous address wasn't unset.

In my database, I have a table called "default_flag", 1 = default, 0 = not default, how can I revert 1 to 0?

address_type_id is for classifying shipping and billing, 1 = shipping and 2 = billing

What should I add in my controller?

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'connect.php';

$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "UPDATE address
        SET address_type_id = 1,
            default_flag = 1
        WHERE id = '$id'";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
header("Location: ../views/user_profile.php");
```

Comment: `if($id = 0){ $sql="UPDATE address  SET address_type_id = 1,  default_flag = 1  WHERE id =0"}`

Comment: It is bad practice to take user input and put it directly into dynamic sql statements. Look into using parameterized queries as your current code is vulnerable to a sql injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

$sql= "UPDATE address SET address_type_id = 1,default_flag = 1 WHERE id = $id";

please print id is coming properly

Answer (score -1):

You can use `1 - VALUE` ( so long as VALUE is either 1 or 0 ) to toggle the state - like so:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "update `address` set `address_type_id` = 1, `default_flag` = 1 - `default_flag` where id = '$id'";
```

If the value is initially 1 it would be come zero and vice-versa.